# A Expectation question

Tags: integral-inequality

I'm not sure if the following statement is right or not. But it looks right to me though I don't know how to prove it. Can someone help?

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ is independent and $EX=EY=0$, do we always have $E(|X+Y|)=E(|X-Y|)$ then? If so, how to prove it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let both $X$ and $Y$ be distributed as follows.  They have value $-1$ with probability $2/3$ and value $2$ with probability $1/3$, so their expectations are $0$ as required.  Since they are independent, $|X+Y|$ takes the value $2$ with probability $4/9$ (when both $X$ and $Y$ are $-1$), the value $1$ with probability $4/9$ (when one of $X$ and $Y$ is $2$ and the other is $-1$), and the value $4$ with probability $1/9$ (when both $X$ and $Y$ are $2$), for an expectation of $16/9$.  Meanwhile, $|X-Y|$ takes, with the same probabilities, values $0$, $3$, and $0$, respectively, for an expectation of $12/9$.

Comment: A little dispressed to see an "example" instead of a prove. Nevertheless, thanks for the nice solution.

Comment: @user84325 I suspect (but haven't checked) that counterexamples are all over the place --- almost any not-too-symmetric distributions for $X$ and $Y$ should give a counterexample.  The one in my answer was just the first not-too-symmetric distribution that happened to occur to me.